# Ошибка установки языковых пакетов

Tags: sudo, linux-mint, linux

Пакет частично установлен, но когда предлагает доустановить через гюи показывается ошибкую А если через терминал командой `sudo aptitude search language-pack-ru`, а потом `sudo aptitude install language-pack-ru` то:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:  firefox-locale-ru{a} language-pack-ru language-pack-ru-base{a} 0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 108 not upgraded.Need to get 245 kB/2 899 kB of archives. After unpacking 11,6 MB will be used.Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] yErr http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main firefox-locale-ru i386 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.154 80]Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main firefox-locale-ru i386 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]0% [Working]E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-ru_12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-ru_12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
```

Как видите, ругается на Firefox. Что делать? Linux mint 13 Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-ru_12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb: 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
>
> Как видите ругается на Firefox. Что делать? Linux mint 13 Cinnamon

Не на Firefox он ругается, а на отсутствие пакета в репозитории.

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get upgrade